# Declaring Variable Runs Variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a functioning search field using `ProductID`, then using this to display the row in the product table where the `ProductID` exists. The problem I am having is that if I have the code as follows: The submit button below executes the `$deleteprod` and `$deltesale` code which all it should (from my understanding) is submit the `ProductID` variable.

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
    <input value="" placeholder="Product ID" name="ProductID" type="text"/> <br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="" value="Search"/
</form>
<?php 

    $ProductID = $_POST['ProductID'];
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "usbw");
    $deleteprod = mysql_query("DELETE FROM gameshop.product WHERE (product.ProductID = '$ProductID')");
    $deletesale = mysql_query("DELETE FROM gameshop.sale WHERE (sale.ProductID = '$ProductID')");
    $deletebutton = "<button onclick=\"$deletesale; $deleteprod; location.href='database.php'\" style='width:200px; background-color:red;'>Delete Row</button>"; 
    mysql_select_db("gameshop",$db);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT product.*, sale.Price
        FROM gameshop.product, gameshop.sale 
        WHERE (product.ProductID = '$ProductID' AND sale.ProductID = '$ProductID')",$db);
    if (!$result){
        print mysql_rror();
    }
    elseif ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<table style='text-align:center;' border=1>\n";
        echo "<tr><td>Product ID</td><td>Product Name</td>", "<td>Publisher</td><td>Developer</td>", "<td>Release Date</td><td>Stock</td>", "<td>Console</td>       <td>Rank</td><td>Price</td><td>Delete?</td></tr>\n";
        do{
            printf("<tr><td>%4d</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%1d</td><td>%s</td><td>%1d</td><td>%2d</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", // %s are syntax (string)
            $myrow["ProductID"], $myrow["ProductName"], $myrow["Publisher"], $myrow["Developer"], $myrow["ReleaseDate"], $myrow["Stock"], $myrow["Console"], $myrow["Rank"], $myrow["Price"], $deletebutton);
        }
        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
        echo "</table>\n";
    }
    mysql_close($db);
?>
```

If I were to move the `$db = MySQL_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "usbw");` to below the `$delete` variables, this problem does not occur and it creates the single row table. However when attempting to click on the `$deletebutton`, the code does not execute and no row is deleted.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The MySQL api is deprecated and should not be used. http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: I don't see what you're trying to do with your button and a PHP function inside it

Comment: If I were you I'd pu an input type radio and ask user if he wants to list products or delete them. And do a simple if/elseif $_POST['choice'] === 'delete' you send delete query, otherwise you insert, and ID will be sent in the form

Comment: I wanted to separate some of the code by incorporating variables because otherwise I thought it would get very messy. Could that be the problem?

Comment: You can't use PHP this way. That's all I'm saying. You could make life simpler by digging into forms and just get the good conditions for good action in your php script

Comment: PHP ain't JS, you can't ask browser to retrieve your PHP function. So you need to make your form or your php file cleaner to get good results

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#forms  https://gyazo.com/be05e9668bbde750f65c68406d36e1ff

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Also, **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even do this is a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Anyway your problem is because you aren't checking which action the user chose when running your code. You just run all of it every time. You don't even wait for the user to submit the form before trying to execute it! This will run the first time you load the script event (although it will fail since $_POST["productID"] doesn't exist yet, but still you shouldn't even want it to run).

Comment: Also your delete button doesn't transmit any value back to the server to indicate which rows is to be deleted. Even if it did, it's done using a GET so the $_POST variable will never be populated. I suggest you take a basic tutorial about PHP forms which would show you properly how to do this kind of thing and how to structure your code. And find a modern one which uses mysqli or PDO with parameterised queries for the data access. Whatever you have been learning from is many years out of date, and obviously didn't explain some of the basic concepts properly.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, when you click the button you call JavaScript, not PHP.
I think you could solve it making another PHP page with your `deletesale` and `deleteprod` which takes `Product_ID` with `post`. 
so this file would have a php script like this:

```
$ProductID = $_POST['ProductID'];
$db = mysql_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "usbw");
mysql_select_db("gameshop",$db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT product.*, sale.Price
    FROM gameshop.product, gameshop.sale 
    WHERE (product.ProductID = '$ProductID' AND sale.ProductID = '$ProductID')",$db);
if (!$result){
    print mysql_error();
}
elseif ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<table style='text-align:center;' border=1>\n";
    echo "<tr><td>Product ID</td><td>Product Name</td>", "<td>Publisher</td> <td>Developer</td>", "<td>Release Date</td><td>Stock</td>", "<td>Console</td>       <td>Rank</td><td>Price</td><td>Delete?</td></tr>\n";
    do{
        printf("<tr><td>%4d</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%1d</td><td>%s</td><td>%1d</td><td>%2d</td><td>",$myrow["ProductID"], $myrow["ProductName"], $myrow["Publisher"], $myrow["Developer"], $myrow["ReleaseDate"], $myrow["Stock"], $myrow["Console"], $myrow["Rank"], $myrow["Price"]);
        printf "<form method=\"post\" action=\"delete_page.php\"><input type=\"text\" style=\"display:none\" name=\"ProductID\" value=\"$ProductID\"/><input type=\"submit\" value=\"delete product\"/></form>"
        printf "</td></tr>"
    }
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    echo "</table>\n";
}
mysql_close($db);
```

and then you would have `delete_page.php` with

```
$ProductID = $_POST['ProductID'];
$db = mysql_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "usbw");
mysql_select_db("gameshop",$db);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM gameshop.product WHERE (product.ProductID = '$ProductID')");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM gameshop.sale WHERE (sale.ProductID = '$ProductID')");
mysql_close($db);
```

then you can add a link back to the main page.

Be sure to check for typos :)